# R - Identify common elements in data frame columns

Tags: r, unique

How can I identify the elements that are common to ALL columns of this data frame (excluding `NA`). How can I achieve that? I tried some approaches using `intersect` and `unique` without success.

```
 df <- structure(list(cloudiness = structure(1:47, .Label = c("ACCESS1-0", 
"ACCESS1-3", "BNU-ESM", "CCSM4", "CESM1-BGC", "CESM1-CAM5", "CESM1-CAM5-1-FV2", 
"CESM1-FASTCHEM", "CESM1-WACCM", "CMCC-CESM", "CMCC-CM", "CMCC-CMS", 
"CNRM-CM5", "CNRM-CM5-2", "CSIRO-Mk3-6-0", "CanESM2", "FGOALS-g2", 
"FIO-ESM", "GFDL-CM3", "GFDL-ESM2G", "GFDL-ESM2M", "GISS-E2-H", 
"GISS-E2-H-CC", "GISS-E2-R", "GISS-E2-R-CC", "HadCM3", "HadGEM2-AO", 
"HadGEM2-CC", "HadGEM2-ES", "IPSL-CM5A-LR", "IPSL-CM5A-MR", "IPSL-CM5B-LR", 
"MIROC-ESM", "MIROC-ESM-CHEM", "MIROC4h", "MIROC5", "MPI-ESM-LR", 
"MPI-ESM-MR", "MPI-ESM-P", "MRI-CGCM3", "MRI-ESM1", "NorESM1-M", 
"NorESM1-ME", "bcc-csm1-1", "bcc-csm1-1-m", "concat", "inmcm4"
), class = "factor"), humidity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), .Label = c("ACCESS1-0", "ACCESS1-3", "BNU-ESM", "CCSM4", 
"CESM1-BGC", "CESM1-CAM5", "CESM1-FASTCHEM", "CESM1-WACCM", "CNRM-CM5", 
"CSIRO-Mk3-6-0", "CanESM2", "GFDL-CM3", "GFDL-ESM2G", "GFDL-ESM2M", 
"GISS-E2-H", "GISS-E2-H-CC", "GISS-E2-R", "GISS-E2-R-CC", "HadCM3", 
"HadGEM2-AO", "HadGEM2-CC", "HadGEM2-ES", "IPSL-CM5A-MR", "IPSL-CM5B-LR", 
"MIROC-ESM", "MIROC-ESM-CHEM", "MIROC4h", "MIROC5", "MRI-CGCM3", 
"MRI-ESM1", "NorESM1-M", "NorESM1-ME", "bcc-csm1-1", "bcc-csm1-1-m", 
"inmcm4"), class = "factor"), precipitation = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("BNU-ESM", "CCSM4", "CESM1-BGC", 
"CESM1-CAM5", "CESM1-FASTCHEM", "CESM1-WACCM", "CMCC-CESM", "CMCC-CMS", 
"CNRM-CM5-2", "CanCM4", "CanESM2", "FGOALS-g2", "FIO-ESM", "GFDL-CM2p1", 
"GFDL-CM3", "GFDL-ESM2M", "GISS-E2-H", "GISS-E2-H-CC", "GISS-E2-R", 
"GISS-E2-R-CC", "HadCM3", "HadGEM2-AO", "HadGEM2-CC", "HadGEM2-ES", 
"IPSL-CM5A-LR", "IPSL-CM5A-MR", "IPSL-CM5B-LR", "MIROC-ESM", 
"MIROC-ESM-CHEM", "MIROC4h", "MIROC5", "MPI-ESM-LR", "MPI-ESM-MR", 
"MPI-ESM-P", "MRI-CGCM3", "MRI-ESM1", "NorESM1-M", "NorESM1-ME", 
"bcc-csm1-1", "bcc-csm1-1-m", "inmcm4"), class = "factor"), temperature = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), wind = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ACCESS1-0", "ACCESS1-3", 
"BNU-ESM", "CMCC-CESM", "CMCC-CM", "CMCC-CMS", "CNRM-CM5", "CNRM-CM5-2", 
"CSIRO-Mk3-6-0", "CanESM2", "GFDL-CM2p1", "GFDL-CM3", "GFDL-ESM2G", 
"GFDL-ESM2M", "GISS-E2-H", "GISS-E2-H-CC", "GISS-E2-R", "GISS-E2-R-CC", 
"HadCM3", "HadGEM2-AO", "HadGEM2-CC", "HadGEM2-ES", "IPSL-CM5A-LR", 
"IPSL-CM5A-MR", "IPSL-CM5B-LR", "MIROC-ESM", "MIROC-ESM-CHEM", 
"MIROC4h", "MIROC5", "MPI-ESM-LR", "MPI-ESM-MR", "MPI-ESM-P", 
"MRI-CGCM3", "MRI-ESM1", "NorESM1-M", "NorESM1-ME", "bcc-csm1-1", 
"bcc-csm1-1-m", "inmcm4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cloudiness", 
"humidity", "precipitation", "temperature", "wind"), row.names = c(NA, 
-47L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?  Did you mean to subset the rows that have the same values for each column?

Comment: For example, "HadCM3" is common to all columns (except temperature which is NA).

Comment: I checked `HadCM3`..  `which(df[,1]=='HadCM3')
#[1] 26;
 which(df[,2]=='HadCM3')
#[1] 19`, it is not common for the same row.  It is common to all the columns, but in different row.  So, I am not sure how your expected result would look like

Comment: The row doesn't really matter. I am looking for all the elements that are present in the columns cloudiness, humidity, precipitation and wind (let's exclude temperature for now). If it is present in all the columns, no matter the row, then it interests me.

Comment: May be `lst1 <- lapply(df, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]); Reduce(intersect,lst1[sapply(lst1, length)>0])`

Comment: NorESM1-M is also present in all columns (except temperature, of course). Therefore, so far, the resulting list would include HadCM3 and NorESM1-M

Comment: You nailed it! Can you please post your code as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `Reduce` with `intersect` after removing the columns that are all `NAs` (`colSums[!is.na(df))!=0]`)

```
Reduce(intersect,df[colSums(!is.na(df))!=0])
#[1] "BNU-ESM"        "CanESM2"        "GFDL-CM3"       "GFDL-ESM2M"    
#[5] "GISS-E2-H"      "GISS-E2-H-CC"   "GISS-E2-R"      "GISS-E2-R-CC"  
#[9] "HadCM3"         "HadGEM2-AO"     "HadGEM2-CC"     "HadGEM2-ES"    
#[13] "IPSL-CM5A-MR"   "IPSL-CM5B-LR"   "MIROC-ESM"      "MIROC-ESM-CHEM"
#[17] "MIROC4h"        "MIROC5"         "MRI-CGCM3"      "MRI-ESM1"      
#[21] "NorESM1-M"      "NorESM1-ME"     "bcc-csm1-1"     "bcc-csm1-1-m"  
#[25] "inmcm4"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It would take a long time to figure it out and your answer does it all.